# No response while downloading large video file using HttpClient in windows phone 10

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I'm using the following code snippet to download large videos (size: less than 14MB). It works fine in windows phone 8.1 device but gets stuck forever while executing the same in windows phone 10 device. 
It downloads small files (about 1MB size) in Windows Phone 10 device but stucks forever while downloading large video file without catching any exception.

```
try
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(url + "?refresh=" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3);
    var httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
    httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    byte[] dataByte = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

    StorageFolder appFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    StorageFile file = await appFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(file, dataByte);
    return "success";
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Comment: Hi Kishor, yes facing the same issue in my Windows 10 phone? Any geniuses around here to solve this?

Comment: Some questions need your response: 1. Windows Mobile OS version 2. Looks like you are using System.Net.Http.HttpClient, have you wrapped this function in a Runtime Component/Class Library or Just keep in code behind?

Comment: Hi Franklin, I have kept this code in my Windows Runtime Component. My project is a WinJS project so I'm calling native functions from JS.
 And OS build: 10.0.10586.420   Version: 1511  Device: Microsoft Lumia 640 XL Dual Sim